# UI performance issue

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm intermediate on Android development and I heard about `ConstraintLayout` for best performance because I have to make a complex UI like this as an item for `RecyclerView`:

[image: UI Screen shot]

Of course, not all details will be shown so I use groups to achieve hiding.
I have a lag when scrolling and I tried `StableId` and it duplicates items.
I tried `hasFixedSize` the same problem exists.
So, how can I improve my UI to prevent lag as much as possible.

[My UI Code](https://gist.github.com/alihabbash/b1484af0f1029005ed06d76981d4f927)

**Edit 1**: I have tried to remove details section and the performance was improved.

**Edit 2**: The `logcat` shows this error message

```
 The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**Edit 3**: My Adapter Code is [Adapter Code](https://gist.github.com/alihabbash/d29d680fbe1087f781b65821523de7ea)

Comment: I see that your layout contains only `TextView`, and it's not that much to get lag, `RecyclerView` is already improved for scroll effect. `ConstraintLayout` comes when your content is hardcode data that cannot be grouped as a list, but I don't think it will help you get rid of lag. It has to be something else loading in the background, try to remove some items to see if the problem still there

Comment: I have tried to remove details sections and the performance has improved, I have edited my question to include the adapter too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding this to your recyclerview:

> android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"

Like discribed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491423/8471329).

Comment: Thank you so much, I have put the `recyclerView` inside the `NestedScrollView` to make it works perfectly without that the `nestedScrollEnabled` has no effect.